# Ruby - gsub br tags to \n\n for API, but including any whitespace

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I've got `<br>` tags in my client's data that I need to replace with '\n\n' in my Rails API for a React Native app.

Sometimes there are spaces before or after the `<br>` tag, or both.

I'm looking for a `gsub` to say "any `<br>` tag, and also include any whitespace before or after it, replace with '\n\n'.

Right now I'm doing:

```
module ApiHelper
  def parse_newlines(string)
    string = string.gsub('<br>', '\n\n')
    string = string.gsub(' <br>', '\n\n')
    string = string.gsub('<br> ', '\n\n')
    string = string.gsub(' <br> ', '\n\n')
  end
end
```

Is there something cleaner?

EDIT: Thanks all. I want to accept both Gavin's and the Tin Man's answers...Gavin because he gave me the down and dirty solution, but Tin Man for such a great/in depth explanation on a more robust way using Nokogiri...

2nd EDIT: I take it back. Tin man...using Nokogiri is actually much more readable. Your argument about using regex's in your comment is valid. In the end your code is easier to understand. Giving you the accepted answer, even though I am using Gavin's for now.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". Provide a working, minimal, example of your code along with the necessary input (minimal HTML) that demonstrates the problem. Asking us to create the HTML wastes our time and slows us when helping you and others. It's possible to run into `< br>`, `<br >`, `<br/>` or worse. Don't use regex or string manipulation to change HTML; It'll make you go nuts. Instead use a parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When messing with HTML or XML it's better to use a parser. I'd start with:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(<<EOT)
<p>this<br>is<br> some <br>
text<br>and<br >some<br/>more</p>
EOT

doc.search('br').each { |br| br.replace("\n\n") }
doc.to_html
# => "<p>this\n" +
#    "\n" +
#    "is\n" +
#    "\n" +
#    " some \n" +
#    "\n" +
#    "\n" +
#    "text\n" +
#    "\n" +
#    "and\n" +
#    "\n" +
#    "some\n" +
#    "\n" +
#    "more</p>\n"
```

Whitespace in HTML displayed by a browser is gobbled by the browser so space runs, or multiple returns will be reduced to a single space or a single line unless you wrap it with `<pre>` tags or do something similar.

If you absolutely need to strip spaces before and after where you're inserting new-lines, I'd use an extra step:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(<<EOT)
<p>this<br>is<br> some <br>
text<br>and<br >some<br/>more</p>
EOT

doc.search('p').each do |p|
  p.inner_html = p.inner_html.gsub(/ +</, '<').gsub(/> +/, '>')
end 

doc.to_html
# => "<p>this<br>is<br>some<br>\n" +
#    "text<br>and<br>some<br>more</p>\n"

doc.search('br').each { |br| br.replace("\n\n") }
doc.to_html
# => "<p>this\n" +
#    "\n" +
#    "is\n" +
#    "\n" +
#    "some\n" +
#    "\n" +
#    "\n" +
#    "text\n" +
#    "\n" +
#    "and\n" +
#    "\n" +
#    "some\n" +
#    "\n" +
#    "more</p>\n"
```

Note: Technically, `<br>` is equivalent to a single "\n", not "\n\n". `<p>` would be two new-lines because that constitutes a paragraph.

Comment: Thanks for all these details! Yeah, I realized that I needed two lines instead of one. The data came from word/excel from the client, and they had these  ¶ symbols, which I mistakenly replaced with only one <br> tag at first. Then realized I couldn't use the <br> tags in react native, I needed to use /n. Then realized I actually needed two /n.

Comment: Nokogiri seems pretty great. I may have to do some more robust parsing later and this will be helpful. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This'll do it:

```
module ApiHelper
  def parse_newlines(string)
    # Handles <br>, <br/>, <br />
    string.gsub(/\s*<br\s*?\/?>\s*/, "\n\n")
  end
end

# irb
> parse_newlines("     <br>      ")
=> "\n\n"
> parse_newlines("     <br />      ")
=> "\n\n"
> parse_newlines("<br />")
=> "\n\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
string = 'Lorem <br> Ipsum'
puts string.gsub(/\s(<br>)\s/, '\n\n')
# => Lorem\n\nIpsum
puts string.gsub(/\s(<br>)\s/, "\n\n")
# Lorem
# 
# Ipsum
```

And note the difference between `'\n\n'` and `"\n\n"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
module ApiHelper
  def parse_newlines(string)
    string.gsub(/\s*<br>\s*/, "\n\n")
  end
end
```